# Angular: Accessing ViewChildren in createComponent loop

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create Angular4 components dynamically from JSON that might have a structure like this (pseudo):

```
-TabContainerComponent
-- TabComponent
--- TextInputComponent
--- ComboboxComponent
-- TabComponent
--- WhateverComponent
```

So there is always a single root component and if it offers transclusion (meaning that it has an `<ng-content>` in his template), it has a collection of n children.

In a template, this JSON would translate to something like

```
<tab-container>
    <tab>
        <text-input></text-input>
        <combobox></combobox>
    </tab>
    <tab>
        <whatever></whatever>
    </tab>
</tab-container>
```

Now I'm trying to create this DOM in code using `viewContainer.createComponent`. I basically iterate over each node in my deserialized JSON and pass it to this function:

```
// T is for example TabComponent or WhateverComponent
const childComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(<Type<{}>>T);     
const result: ComponentRef<{}> = parentNode.createComponent(childComponent);
```

The top-level `parentNode` is a static div in my template and the root node for all of this creation magic.

Now, as you can imagine, components often need to access their `@ViewChildren` in `AfterContentInit`. For example, the TabContainer might try to auto-select the first tab like this:

```
@ContentChildren(TabComponent)
public tabs: QueryList<TabComponent>;

public ngAfterContentInit() {
    const activeTabs = this.tabs.filter((tab) => tab.isActive);
    if (activeTabs.length === 0) {
        this.selectTab(this.tabs.first);
    }
}
```

The problem is: As soon as I call `viewContainer.createComponent`, the created component runs through all of its lifecycle events - which is before its children were deserialized and created. On the other hand, I can't traverse my JSON from bottom to top and start with the lowest children because I need to call `createComponent` on a parentNode that wouldn't exist yet either.

The whole transclusion mechanism works fine by the way. I can see all the desired nodes in the DOM but am always unable to access my ViewChildren.

Do you have any idea how to resolve this? Can I create components without actually "bringing them to life"? Is there another life cycle hook that I should use or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: _As soon as I call viewContainer.createComponent, the created component runs through all of its lifecycle events_ - that's not true, it will run later when cahnage detection happens

Comment: Can you create plunker to reproduce your problem?